# Centos 6.2 - Apache 2 - PHP 5 - Blank result executing

Tags: php, linux, exec, ping

I have one issue executing 'ping' on PHP, I received a blank result  but if I execute other command like a 'whoami' I received a right result, Could you help me please? any Idea?

```
<?php
exec('ping google.com', $output);
echo $output;
//Result: 
?>

<?php
exec('whoami', $output);
echo $output;
//Result: apache
?>
```

Thanks

Note: Maybe can be some from apache config? or php config? or linux permission?

Comment: I'd like to note that `$output` will be an array, so you can't just echo it directly if the output will span multiple lines (like with a ping).

Comment: yes I tried but doesn't work, `<?php
echo exec('ping google.com');
//Result: 
?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
<?php
function GetPing($ip=NULL) {
 if(empty($ip)) {$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];}
 if(getenv("OS")=="Windows_NT") {
  $exec = exec("ping -n 3 -l 64 ".$ip);
  return end(explode(" ", $exec ));
 }
 else {
  $exec = exec("ping -c 3 -s 64 -t 64 ".$ip);
  $array = explode("/", end(explode("=", $exec )) );
  return ceil($array[1]) . 'ms';
 }
}

echo GetPing();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks but in all cases I received 0ms, even with external host like 8.8.8.8 (google's dns)

Comment: Sorry but the same history, Result: 0ms pinging to google.com

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's cos the default behavoir of ping is to never stop. It keeps going until you kill it.

man ping says " -c count
              Stop  after  sending count ECHO_REQUEST packets. With deadline option, ping waits for count ECHO_REPLY packets, until the
              timeout expires."

Try adding options to limit pings run-time and see if you get a result.

Comment: I tied but doesn't work It. I tied run a simple command ping in wamp (windows os) and run perfectly but in Linux don't

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this one

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('ping google.com');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but don't work only the server responded this html. "<pre></pre>"